# Testing for microservices

Tags: testing, microservices

I have an application which consists of a few microservices. For example:

- Authnenticate service
- Messanger service.

To auth I use JWT. 
If I want to test API in "Messanger service" first I have to get JWT from "Authnenticate service". But send request to production "Authnenticate service" it's bad idea (I think so).

I see a few solutions:

- Use "hardcode" JWT in my unittest.
- Turn off auth check in my api for unittests.

How do you make unittests in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use the requests for real authentication.

For simple unit tests you can simply hard code your JWT token in your unit test and simply test your functions. That is the easiest and best way to do unit tests.

Comment: Yes, I think about your first suggestion. But it implies I have to run authentication service for unittest. It means that tests will be more complex. So if I want to test each microservice I should run all microservices, am I right? And I should run microservices in testing environment not production, of course.

Comment: Not really. You just need to get the jwt token in the beginning of all unit tests and store it in a variable. Then you can use the jwt token easily.
But therefore Unittests are 'locally' you do not really need any authentication.